# Why not always use 2x images when building web pages?

Tags: html, css, web, retina-display

I was having a discussion with a designer friend yesterday, the salient points of which I'll detail below:

- 2x images are larger files, but not the 4x you may think. In one example a 1x image file is 47kb & its 2x counterpart is only 55kb.
- 2x images are only for Retina screens, and despite being phased in on the desktop/laptop side, the truth is that most retina screens are mobile.
- While wifi is becoming fairly ubiquitous, desktops (mostly 1x) are the only devices that never have to download data off a cell network.

These all led me to posit the question: Why are we spending energy on providing 2x images, when they are mostly accessed by mobile devices which have the greatest bandwidth limitations?

After sleeping on it, I started to wonder: well fine, if we're going to ignore that last issue, why not just only deal in 2x? CSS can handle scaling down the images in any case (perhaps I'm wrong here?) so why not save the media queries & save the effort to generate and store 2 copies of every image by just using 2x everywhere?

Am I crazy?

Comment: "Am I crazy?" = no. (I think you pretty much covered all the answers answers in your question!) :)

Comment: Haha well thanks I guess :) I'm only asking because there seem to be lots of projects aimed at helping people use 1x & 2x together in web development, and I don't understand all the effort there.

Comment: SVG for vector images, and there's now http://scottjehl.github.io/picturefill/ for 1x and 2x images and different sizes at certain breakpoints.

Answer (score 0):

The file size issue does bother me. I think things should be as small as possible.

If you're not worried about that, though, the only, temporary issue I can think of is browser support for `background-size`. IE8 doesn't support it and it's still used enough to have to worry about it (at least on my projects). There's a polyfill for it, but it's not up to snuff with the real thing.

Comment: Yeah I think IE8 is still ~ 20% of the Internet so that's a good point. What is the polyfill you have experience with? What about it is not up to snuff?

Comment: Here's a few of the limitations on the one I've used: https://github.com/louisremi/background-size-polyfill#limitations

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer depends on where you live in the world. Believe it or not, I live in an area with a lot of country roads that still only have dial-up. Sometimes, even that does not work. We are still not nearly as high-speed as we should be with desktops. I can't imagine them having to download that extra data when they view 1x.

So, I think it depends on your target audience, where they are more likely to live or what devices they use. We will get there in time, but for some, not yet.

Answer (score 0):

**Let analytics be your guide**

I use the 5% rule. Once any feature is more than 2 standard deviations out of the norm, I drop support for it. In browserland, that means IE6 and IE7 are gone for me but I keep supporting IE8 because a size-able chunk of the audience is using that feature. Yeah the big guys like Google have dropped it but I still see a good chunk of traffic from it on a lot of sites. Why make them suffer?

Now how this relates to your question: ask yourself what percentage of your audience is on a 10Mbps+ LTE connection with retina screen. Maybe in your case it's 95% retina screens with LTE on mobile, but check your analytics package. My guess is that it's probably under 20%, in which case having fall-backs gives a better UX to 80% of your audience - easily worth the effort.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion I see those problems:

- some older phone models (ex: iPhone 3G) and tablets (ex: iPad 1) have low memory. A big enough image can cause out of memory errors.
- to scale an image the system has to load it at full size and do a complex scaling operation each time it draws it (sometimes it is cached).
- a scaled down image doesn't look as good.
- you can run into problems with them in older browsers (as mentioned by Bill Criswell)
- it increases download size. If we consider a 10kb increase in size / picture * 10 pictures per page than you get 100kb per page load. If your page has to display a lot of images (think social), than the overhead is a lot.
- you can improve your search engine rankings if your page loads faster and it is smaller.

Answer (score 0):

The only major issue is file size. And as you state, in a lot of cases, the file size differences are minimal.

If we're talking mostly icons, the benefit is that a) icons aren't huge to begin with, so the file size increase is minimal and b) icons benefit the most from retina resolution.

On the other hand, if we're talking 'full screen' news photos, those could be quite a bit larger file-size-wise, but also look perfectly fine if they are not retina (as they are continuous tone) so there's a less compelling need to make those retina if you are targeting a mobile device.

A compromise for the latter might be to lazy-load them. Check the screen size. If phone-sized, load the regular image and call it good. If it's larger than phone size, load the regular image, then go back and grab the retina version for those on an iPad 3, for example.

The only technical problem is IE8 and older. They can't handle the CSS you'd typically use for retina images. There are workarounds, but not for sprites--which you'd commonly use for icons.

Eventually, we'll see more SVG support, which will solve this problem--at least for icons. When I am doing pure iOS work, for example, most all of my imagery is SVG now. It's smaller, and automatically retina-ready.